# C#, after execution of a stored procedure, is it possible to revert back the changes made through stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am executing a stored procedure, with the result returned from the stored procedure I am doing certain operations. Note: Data have been added in certain tables on execution of the stored procedure.

If some error occurs after the execution of the stored procedure, I would like to revert the changes made through the stored procedure as well, the data altered/added through stored procedure ceased to exist.

The code is something like below.

```
var result = ExecuteStoredProc("SPToBeExecuted");

var spResult = result[0].Cast<Customer>().ToArray();

//Operations performed using spResult
//error occurs in operation performed using spResult

//commit Transaction
```

Before committing the transaction, how can I revert back the changes made through the stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried with .Net Transaction Scope?

Comment: Using a transaction scope worked, I guessed it wouldn't work as the changes were made through a SP. Thanks.

Comment: It is not SP or not, the C# Transaction Scope will handle the scope in C# code, SPs.

Comment: The transaction scope works i.e Rolls back the changes while debugging, but, it does not work when deployed in IIS server version.

Answer (score 1):

> Before committing the transaction, how can I revert back the changes

If you're already working with a transaction, then you should simply **rollback** the transaction. That's the purpose of a transaction: you either commit it or roll it back in case you want to revert.

Since you haven't posted the actual transaction code, I can't show you a working example.